# System Ruby wins over rbenv Everytime on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ruby, raspberry-pi, rbenv

[image]

As you may tell from the screenshot I have included.  I'm trying to get rbenv ruby 2.1.2 to replace the system ruby on Raspberry pi and there's no earthly reason it should still be pointed at 1.9.3!

Comment: What is the output of `which ruby`? What is the output of `source ~/.bashrc` followed by `which ruby`?

Comment: `which ruby` yields `/usr/bin/ruby` and then `source ~/.bashrc` just shows the next line and then `which ruby` is the same `/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: 1. Run `rbenv rehash`. 2. Give us the output of `ls -l ~/.rbenv/shims`. 3. Try `which ruby` and `ruby -v` again . 4. Make the PATH variable `$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH`. If it still doesn't work, give us the output of `env`.

Comment: Still no go:  Screen shot -> http://imgur.com/eldzpPw  -  Gist of files here:  .bashrc -> http://pastebin.com/mfGX4Lg7 , env -> http://pastebin.com/hR06FyRm , .profile -> http://pastebin.com/WWRahYsr

Comment: Empty `~/.rbenv/shims` is bad. On my system, there is a file named `ruby` in there which does the work of loading the right ruby. Can you try re-installing rbenv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a lot of help from @dteoh, I was finally able to ascertain how this happened.

As it turns out, when I was doing my `rbenv install 2.1.2` the process was taking so long I went to bed.  I didn't put it together until the `~/.rbenv/shims` was empty, but one of my digital clocks was blinking.  Apparently that night I lost power in the night, which put it in some strange state.

**The fix was blowing away the Ruby version and doing another (long) but successful Ruby build.**

Thank you for your patience in this RARE but troublesome situation.

Comment: Resulting HOW-TO for Ruby and Rails and Rbenv.  Again, mucho thanks to user dteoh

http://www.iconoclastlabs.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-on-the-raspberry-pi-b-with-rbenv

Answer (score -1):

run `rbenv version`, you may find that a env var named `RBENV_VERSION` was set, after unsetting the env var using `export RBENV_VERSION=`, you will have the correct ruby version

Comment: `$rbenv version` returns `2.1.2 (set by /home/pi/.rbenv/version)`